# Android: GET works, POST doesnt

Tags: android, json, post, get

i'm currently testing some code to get used with android programming. I found some testproject here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

But the problem is, i can read the database with no problem but the functions doesnt work with POST only GET. So when i try to add a new product it does the request to my php script but there is no POST data at all. I tested it this way:

```
<?php 
header("content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");
//print("fda");
/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
//if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {
//if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = "test";//$_POST['name'];
    $price = 123; //$_POST['price'];
    $description = "desc"; //$_POST['description'];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
 $data = $data." Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value);
    // include db connect class
//echo $data;
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description, url) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description','$data')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created!.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
//} else {
//    // required field is missing
//    $response["success"] = 0;
//    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
//
//    // echoing JSON response
//    echo json_encode($response);
//}
?>
```

As you see, i post the POST data in the database. When i use my own webbased testscript it works perfectly and it shows the POST data in the database.

So my android code doesnt seem to send the POST data actually because it will add a row in the database when i add a product but with the testvars offcourse. The problem is, when i execute it from my phone, the last field in the database (url or better params) will stay empty.

Here is the code from the android application:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://www.supergeilebus.nl/android_connect/create_product.php/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method


            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,"POST", params);
            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. I'm out of options. When i change everything to GET it works perfectly. I know it is very poor coded because of the sql injections but i just want to learn of this.

Greets and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi User i uses following code to call post to web service . it may help u.

```
**public String doPost(Activity activity, String urlString, String method, String value) 
                                                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
    {
        String responseString="";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        retryCount++;
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString+method);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");  
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",value.length()+"" );  
            urlConnection.setDoInput( true );
            urlConnection.setDoOutput( true );
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( urlConnection.getOutputStream() );
            byte[] bs = value.getBytes();
            Log.d(tag, "Sending JSON String ->"+new String(bs));
            dos.write(bs);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            Log.d(tag,"Responce ->"+urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            if(urlConnection.getResponseMessage().toLowerCase().equals("ok"))
            {
                InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                int ch;
                StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
                while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 )
                {
                    b.append( (char)ch );
                }
                responseString = b.toString();
                Log.d(tag,method + "','" + responseString);
                return method + "','" + responseString;
            }
            else
            {

                Log.d(tag, tag1+urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }
            dos.close();
        } 
        catch (SocketException e) 
        {

            Log.d(tag, tag1+e);

    }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

            Log.e(tag,"-->"+ e);
        }

        return "";
    }**
```

Here urlString and method make whole URL of web service method.

Comment: Hi, thx for calling me User, i saw that i didnt had a name.

But back on topic, I tried it but i dont have success actually. It allso doesnt seem to send any POST message. Maybe there is a need to import some extra file somewhere? Maybe it is send in the wrong sentence?

Comment: Hi liquidacid, Sorry to call u user bcoz i was working on class named as user. In it i post a json sting. No u dont need any external file or jar to make this call.